# Why does the grease Pencil Fill becomes transparent when zoomed out

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil, 2d

I'm trying to draw an oil tanker with a combination of a 3D mold and 2D drawings with grease pencil, but when the grease drawings are close to a 3D mesh or another Grease pencil object, it becomes transparent so I see the lines behind it and the fill mixes with the colors behind it, also the closest the camera is to the object the worst.

example: I have a 3D box made with grease pencil rectangles when I'm close it looks how it's supposed to look but when I zoom out I can see the lines behind

[image: object close]
[image: object zoomed out]

So this with the right zoom it looks ok but when I zoom out it goes crazy. On the GPencil layers, I already set the strokes depth order to 3D Location so I don't understand why this is happening, what am I missing? is there any way to fix this issue?

[image: with the right zoom] 
[image: when zoomed out, on top how the bow should look]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you've figured out a solution for this problem, but if not, this could be worth a shot:

- Select Grease Pencil object
- Add an "Offset" modifier
- Try changing the *Location* value by either +0.01 or -0.01 across each axis, then render the results to see if it's fixed the issue. Do it one at a time; you're basically testing which axis the grease pencil needs to be "pushed away from the object" & towards the camera on for it to display properly.

I've had a similar issue which only happens the further the object gets away from the camera. Up close is fine, then if I zoom out, I've had to use this offset modifier & change the location value for my Y axis to -0.02 .. then keyframe it back to 0 when moving back in. The further away the object is, Blender seems to get confused by how close the grease pencil is to another GP object or a 3D object, hence using the offset to move it further away.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your answer, well actually this also happens when I don't have any objects but GP objects, for example, the red box and the railing are both GP and you can see the part that is supposed to be behind (white railing). I tried changing location and it works but if I move the camera, then it happens again I'm using blender 2.82, what version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is no longer happening in version 2.90 alpha, no matter the zoom level, the closest workaround without changing version is the answer given by **j davis**

[image: file in version 2.82]
[image: file in version 2.9 alpha]